# What is the best way to create remote tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

I have 3 Linux servers:

- 10.0.0.0/24 - (10.0.0.10) Linux server inside my LAN.
- 20.0.0.0/24 - (20.0.0.10) Linux server with HTTP Apache server
- 50.50.50.50/32 - Server on Amazon AWS which see both 10.x and 20.x LANs.

10.x cannot see 20.x and 20.x cannot see 10.x
What is the best way (and how can I do it) to se 50.50.50.50 server on AWS to create tunnel from 10.x to 20.x

20.0.0.10 runs HTTPd server on "DMZ" LAN. 
I need to see 20.0.0.10:80 from my 10.0.0.0/24 servers.
The 2 networks 10.x and 20.x is on the same Cisco ASA firewall/router, but I cannot route because of License issues, so i want to bypass this by external server which can see 20.x network. 
I want to be able to go to 50.50.50.50:80 from 10.x servers and see 20.0.0.10:80 content.

Comment: It seems to me that there are already two tunnels so that none needs to be created any more. In that case you just have to (a) configure routing in both networks (making the tunnel address of 50.50.50.50 the gateway for the other network) and (b) allow forwarding between the two tunnel interfaces on 50.50.50.50.

Comment: So instead of Tunnel I need to make 50.50.50.50 as a router?

Comment: If that's what you want. You could also create a direct tunnel between the networks but that would be completely independent of 50.50.50.50.

Comment: Actually I dont want to be able to route back from 20.x to 10.x (10.x is my private internal LAN and 20.x is my "DMZ" ) so it looks like tunnel is my best option here, no?

Comment: Is 20.0.0.0/24 actually available for local use? I thought only 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16 were available for local use.

Comment: 20.0.0.0/24 is real IP , assume it is my website..

Comment: Keep in mind, that in case with port forwarding all your traffic between servers is plain and easily accessible for third party, while in case with ssh tunnel it is encrypted. May be this is important for you.

Comment: not much, it is http website, it is fine. just for learning do you have any example of ssh tunneling? I tried online tutorial (ssh -L 80:20.0.0.10:80 root@20.0.0.10) and I cannot access from 10.0.0.10 to 50.50.50.50:80.. am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Yep, `-L` means you're binding local port, so you have to open 10.0.0.10:80 instead of 50.50.50.50:80 . If you want to open 50.50.50.50:80 use `-R`. Also there is `-C` option in ssh which can compress and save your traffic a little bit.

Comment: So i need to run on 50.x : ssh -R 80:20.0.0.10:80 root@20.0.0.10 ? I run it and when I am trying to surf to 50.50.50.50:80 i am not getting anything.. Cannot understood why..

Answer (score 0):

You describe quite different cases in your question. If you want to reach only 20.x:80 via 50.50.50.50:80 then you can configure port forwarding on 50.50.50.50 with `iptables`:

```
target_ip="20.1.2.3"
source_ip="50.50.50.50"
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 20.1.2.3
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -d "$target_ip" -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source "$source_ip"
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/8 -d "$target_ip" -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/8 -s "$target_ip" -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If there is a tunnel between 20.0.0.0/8 and 50.50.50.50 then you probably have to set `$source_ip` to the tunnel interface IP address.

Comment: I probably misunderstood the terms. Tunnel is the ability to access specific machine you cannot access directly, with another server which can access to the machine, no? so it is my case here - I need to access 20.0.0.10 (assume it is real external valid IP) from 10.0.0.10 (Private LAN - non legal IP). 10.x cannot see 20.x , but EC2 machine can see it..

Comment: "Tunnel" is a general term. My understanding of it is: You create a transparent connection between hosts or networks in both directions. Thus I would not call port forwarding a tunnel. And you would call the connecting system a router rather than a server.